# DOM not getting updated Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
<li
            v-for="(schema) in typeSchema"
            :key="schema.id"
        >
            <div style="display:inline-block; width:100%;">
                <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between">
                    <span>{{ schema.title }}</span>
                    <span v-if="schema.controller">
                        <MdsSwitch
                            :checked="schema.controller.value"
                            :label="schema.controller.title"
                            @change="toggleController(schema, $event)"
                        />
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div style="display:flex;flex-flow:column;place-items:flex-start;align-items:flex-start;margin-top:10px;">
                    <component
                        :is="schema.type"
                        v-bind="schema"
                        :data="data"
                        :is-disabled="schema.isDisabled"
                        @input="updateData"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

```
# toggleController(schema, event) {
            if (schema.controller) {
                // this.typeSchema.map(x => x).in
                schema.controller.value = event;
                schema.isDisabled = !event;
                schema = { ...schema };
                // const index = this.typeSchema.findIndex((x) => x.id === schema.id);
                // console.log(index);
                // this.$set(schema, "isDisabled", !event);
                // this.typeSchema.splice(index, 0, schema);
            }
        },
```

When toggleController is executed it should disable the associated component, it was working earlier and I'm not sure what change I made and it stopped working, unfortunately everything is on my local so cannot refer pervious versions.

I have tried $set, splice but no luck

Comment: Only thing I noticed: ```v-bind="schema"``` is the wrong syntax. v-bind has to be associated with an attribute like this: ```v-bind:someattribute="..."```.

Comment: When we use it in this way we don't have to bind each prop. ex if there is the prop name in child component and schema has property name then these get bind together